# SVG - Inline position element after text

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to position SVG several elements inline inside a single SVG.

I have the following:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <use width="28" height="28"class="cls-11"></use>
        <text id="policyRectText" transform="translate(50,20)" class="cls-54">Runs on a small number of endpoints</text>
        <circle r="15" stroke-width="4" transform="translate(250,15)" class="cls-8"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

So to position an element before dynamic text is easy, but how can i position after it?

[image: inline svg]

Comment: call getComputedTextLength on the text and position the other element after that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

First I'm putting the `<text>` in a `<g>` element since it's transformed and I need to get the bounding box:

`let bb = theTransformedText.getBBox();`

Once I have the position and the size of the text (`bb`) I'm using the data to set the `cx` and the `cy` attributes for the circle.

I've commented out the `<use>` element since it has no `xlink:href` attribute.

```js
let bb = theTransformedText.getBBox();
let r = parseFloat(theCircle.getAttribute("r"));// the circle's radius.
let sw = parseFloat(theCircle.getAttribute("stroke-width"));// the stroke width
theCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", bb.x + bb.width + r + sw/2);
// assuming that the font size is 16 you need to offset the circle half font size
theCircle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", bb.y + 8);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -50 400 100">
    <g>
        <!--<use width="28" height="28"class="cls-11"></use>-->
      <g id="theTransformedText">
        <text id="policyRectText" transform="translate(50,20)" class="cls-54">Runs on a small number of endpoints</text>
      </g>
        <circle id="theCircle" r="15" stroke-width="4" class="cls-8"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: i will try this, I am using D3, will this work on D3, since you need to calculate after its been drawn(the text box)